# Is there a way for a web application to report on the quality of the user's internet connection?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, web, signalr

I have an AngularJS web application that is used to run training sessions. During the training sessions it uses SignalR to push a lot of real-time content out to the client web browsers.

Sometimes users complain that it's not working and they aren't seeing new content popping up anymore.

This leads to an investigation as to what went wrong. Sometimes we suspect its due to poor wifi at the users location as the application does require a good connection but this is hard to prove.

Is there a way to show an indicator on the user's screen as to the quality of their connection (bandwidth and ping?)

Then ideally this could be sent at intervals to the backend so there is a record on the server as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just send bunch of requests to your server that are of fixed size and have the client measure the response times? That is how the internet speed tests work more or less. There are a number of open source implementations that you can check. However note that, production environment is not the place to test this. There are plenty of techniques to simulate slow internet connection. That is something you should check for in your dev/test environment, not in production.

Answer (score 1):

You can start a timeout in an inline script block in , which will be run as soon as it's encountered. You would then cancel the timeout when the load event fires. If the timeout ever fires, the page is loading slowly. For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var slowLoad = window.setTimeout( function() {
        alert( "the page is taking its sweet time loading" );
    }, 10 );

    window.addEventListener( 'load', function() {
        window.clearTimeout( slowLoad );
    }, false );
</script>
```

Obviously you would want to replace the alert with something a little more useful like in your case popups for slow internet connection or whatever you wanna show.